# Is it possible to have 2 headers for same section in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I have data in this way

```
January
   14th
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
   13th
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
February
   14th
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
   13th
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
      Cotent A
```

I have thought of an approach which I tried but I am stuck trying to figure out.

First which I thought of.

Nest a collectionView inside a TableView and use TableView header for showing Month Names and then TableView cell will have a collectionView which will intern have collectionView header for showing Dates and then CollectionView cells for showing Content.

```
Table View Header (January)
     TablView Cell -> CollectionView Header (14th)
                          CollectonView Cell  (Content A)
                          CollectonView Cell  (Content A)
                          CollectonView Cell  (Content A)
                      CollectionView Header (13th)
                          CollectonView Cell  (Content A)
                          CollectonView Cell  (Content A)
                          CollectonView Cell  (Content A)
```

But the problem is number of cells in collection view and their height all is dynamic while I am able to control the collectionView, the tableView's cell is hard to manipulate as I have to do it after all my collectionView cells load.

Is there any other way in which I can achieve this ?

Comment: I have a suggestion,- Can we create a custom header cell and add it as a collection 
 view cell at whatever indexPath you want.

Comment: How are you declaring your arrays ?

Comment: Actually I made few changes to my array and it seems to be solution now. Basically I am saving the date (MM/DD/YY) and using Dictionary(grouping: by:) function to group the array with the DateString values I am storing. Now when in collection view header I am checking the dateString if the month component of previous section and current section is not similar I am trying to show a different header section which also has Month (Main Header), if not I am just showing Normal header with Date. Asking me about checking arrays, put me in thought and I came up with this solution. Cheers.